# OpenSSL AES Stream Ciphers in EVP

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, aes

I'm trying to encrypt data on-the-fly from stdin using the EVP functions in OpenSSL. I have the following code which kind of works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h> /* For htonl() */

int do_evp_seal(FILE *rsa_pkey_file, FILE *in_file, FILE *out_file)
{
    int retval = 0;
    RSA *rsa_pkey = NULL;
    EVP_PKEY *pkey = EVP_PKEY_new();
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
    unsigned char buffer[4096];
    unsigned char buffer_out[4096 + EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];
    size_t len;
    int len_out;
    unsigned char *ek = NULL;
    int eklen;
    uint32_t eklen_n;
    unsigned char iv[EVP_MAX_IV_LENGTH];

    if (!PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(rsa_pkey_file, &rsa_pkey, NULL, NULL))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error loading RSA Public Key File.\n");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        retval = 2;
        goto out;
    }

    if (!EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(pkey, rsa_pkey))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA: failed.\n");
        retval = 3;
        goto out;
    }

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
    ek = malloc(EVP_PKEY_size(pkey));

    if (!EVP_SealInit(&ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), &ek, &eklen, iv, &pkey, 1))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "EVP_SealInit: failed.\n");
        retval = 3;
        goto out_free;
    }

    /* First we write out the encrypted key length, then the encrypted key,
     * then the iv (the IV length is fixed by the cipher we have chosen).
     */

    eklen_n = htonl(eklen);
    if (fwrite(&eklen_n, sizeof eklen_n, 1, out_file) != 1)
    {
        perror("output file");
        retval = 5;
        goto out_free;
    }
    if (fwrite(ek, eklen, 1, out_file) != 1)
    {
        perror("output file");
        retval = 5;
        goto out_free;
    }
    if (fwrite(iv, EVP_CIPHER_iv_length(EVP_aes_256_cbc()), 1, out_file) != 1)
    {
        perror("output file");
        retval = 5;
        goto out_free;
    }

    /* Now we process the input file and write the encrypted data to the
     * output file. */

    while ((len = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, in_file)) > 0)
    {
        if (!EVP_SealUpdate(&ctx, buffer_out, &len_out, buffer, len))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "EVP_SealUpdate: failed.\n");
            retval = 3;
            goto out_free;
        }

        if (fwrite(buffer_out, len_out, 1, out_file) != 1)
        {
            perror("output file");
            retval = 5;
            goto out_free;
        }
    }

    if (ferror(in_file))
    {
        perror("input file");
        retval = 4;
        goto out_free;
    }

    if (!EVP_SealFinal(&ctx, buffer_out, &len_out))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "EVP_SealFinal: failed.\n");
        retval = 3;
        goto out_free;
    }

    if (fwrite(buffer_out, len_out, 1, out_file) != 1)
    {
        perror("output file");
        retval = 5;
        goto out_free;
    }

    out_free:
    EVP_PKEY_free(pkey);
    free(ek);

    out:
    return retval;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *rsa_pkey_file;
    int rv;

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <PEM RSA Public Key File>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    rsa_pkey_file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (!rsa_pkey_file)
    {
        perror(argv[1]);
        fprintf(stderr, "Error loading PEM RSA Public Key File.\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    rv = do_evp_seal(rsa_pkey_file, stdin, stdout);

    fclose(rsa_pkey_file);
    return rv;
}
```

The problem is that this encrypts and writes to the output file in blocks of 4096 bytes. Given that I want this to run in a streaming fashion as soon as data is received on STDIN, this won't do.

I've been told it might be something to do with the fact that I'm using CBC mode, and that it's therefore acting as a block cipher. I agree with this in theory, but changing the cipher to something like OFB or CFB (which should transform it to a stream cipher) results in no output being produced at all!

Comment: CTR mode and GCM mode would also be good choices. Both are offline and allow streaming. CTR mode is seekable, if needed.

Comment: It doesn't look like either are supported in the latest OpenSSL. I do think that CFB and OFB should work, I just need an example of how to implement them correctly. I don't think changing the cipher name in my code is enough because it still seems to be using the 4096 byte input buffer.

Comment: You read your input file in chunks of 4096 bytes and then gives this 4096 bytes to EVP_SealUpdate(), so therefor it encrypts in chunks of 4096 bytes. AES in CBC mode actually operates in blocks of 16 bytes, and the output from an encrypt with that mode would thus be a multiplum of 16 bytes.

Comment: So for stream ciphers (or stream modes of block ciphers), should I reduce the input buffer to a being just a single byte so that only one character is encrypted at a time?

Comment: @user4005750 Just give it all the data you have. What makes it streaming is that it would encrypte all the data you pass to it, right away without blocking - instead of waiting for blocks of e.g. 16 bytes before encrypting. By encrypting right away, you allow decrypt to take place right away as well. If running in block mode, some of the bytes might be stuck in the input buffer of the cipher until a full block is present.

Comment: Check the [list on wiki](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP) I can see support for both...